# SQL CHECK constraint issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, check-constraints

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have a table with three columns: `Length`, `StartTime` and `EndTime`. I want to make a CHECK constraint on this table which says that:

```
if Length == NULL then
  StartTime <> NULL and EndTime <> NULL
else
  StartTime == NULL and EndTime == NULL
```

I've begun to try things like this:

```
Length == NULL AND StartTime <> NULL AND EndTime <> NULL
```

Obviously this is not enough, but even this simple expression will not validate. I get the error:

> "Error validating 'CK_Test_Length_Or_Time'. Do you want to edit the constraint?"

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no  == operator in SQL Server. While checking for null you have to use "is"

Please try this:

```
((Length is null AND starttime is not null AND endtime is not null) OR
(Length is not null AND starttime is null AND endtime is null))
```

HTH

Answer (score 4):

```
CHECK ([Length] IS NULL AND [StartTime] IS NOT NULL AND [EndTime] IS NOT NULL
      OR [Length] IS NOT NULL AND [StartTime] IS NULL AND [EndTime] IS NULL))
```